# Pandas (How to Fix): List is actually string and the value of length is misleading

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, count

I have a dataframe with a list of years in the first column. A second column shows the number of years listed in each row.

```
    Years   Count_of_Years
0   []         2
1   []         2
2   ['2021']   6
3   ['2022']   6
4   []         2
```

Which made me think that the contents of each cell is a pure string. And it seems that way when I checked the type:

```
type(df['Years'][0])

str
```

When I convert the column to list `using to_list()`, it shows:

```
df['Years'].to_list()
```

```
 '[]',
 '[]',
 "['2021']",
 "['2021']",
 '[]',
 '[]',
```

How do I convert it so that the `Count_of_Years` shows correct values?

Comment: How did you create such a frame?  The display tends to obsure differences like this, so it's hard to tell when something is a string, a list, or an array.  String to list has to use `eval` (or a more 'secure' `ast` version).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the values in `Years` column are already strings then I would suggest to use the `str.count` method with a regex pattern to find the number of matching occurrences:

```
df['new_count'] = df['Years'].str.count(r'\d{4}')
```

---

```
      Years  Count_of_Years  new_count
0        []               2          0
1        []               2          0
2  ['2021']               6          1
3  ['2022']               6          1
4        []               2          0
```